# Fill Registeration Form by Extracting Information from QR Codes

Tags: android, qr-code, mobile-website

Example, I create a QR code with all of my personal details inside. I open a registration page. I click a button "Auto fill with QR", it fired up a dialogue box which allowed me to browse and select my QR code. All the fields will be filled.

Is it possibles to do that? How long would it took to develop?